# How to trigger an event for the given interval of time repeatedly in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

How to schedule the event, for instance I need to call a method which should perform its action for every given seconds. I'm developing simple windows form app, I tried using like

```
while(true)
{
 methodToBeScheduled();
 Thread.Sleep(60000);
}
```

This particular piece of code makes my application "Not-responding" while its executing. I hope timer can do this or any other logic that you experts suggest, kindly please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Timer`(System.Threading.Timer).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

Timer _timer = null;


_timer = new Timer(o =>
    {
        methodToBeScheduled();
    });
_timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WinForms timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx):

```
Timer _timer;

// In constructor (or anywhere you want to start the timer, e.g. a button event):
_timer = new Timer();
_timer.Interval = 60000;    // milliseconds
_timer.Tick += (sender, e) => methodToBeScheduled();
_timer.Start();
```

This will cause `methodToBeScheduled` to be called once every 60 seconds, roughly. It will be called on the main UI thread, so avoid doing any heavy processing in it.

The advantage of using this timer is that it's built-in, doesn't require thread synchronization, and is simple to use. The disadvantage is that the interval is not exact -- the actual interval will vary depending on what other messages need to be processed in the application, and is also at the mercy of the Windows system clock, which is only accurate to 10-20ms or so.

Comment: Hi Cameron, thanks. How can I set the timer for methodToBeScheduled(); after the button click event, rather from the Constructor.

Comment: @Renish, You simply move the logic to your button click method - however, keep the `Timer` as a property (outside the method), or it could be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Var sequence = Observable.interval(1).publish
Sequence.subscribe ....

Will allow to subscribe to an observable that will fire an onnext every second.  See reactive extension ..

Hate typing on iPads....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are three different types of timers (all of which are named Timer but behave a little different) in .net. The windows.forms timer executes a function at a certain rate--it calls the function from the UI thread. The System.Threading Timer does the same but calls the function from another thread. There is another timer that I can't remember off the top of my head. You will have to pick one of them based on your circumstance.

Threading timer is my favorite. [Here](http://penguin.ewu.edu/class/cscd498/csharp/refdocs/System.Threading/types/Timer.html) is an example if how to use it. Just keep in mind whatever you are calling is not done from the UI thread. May want to use the forms timer or synchronize things if that's an issue.

Comment: I believe the third timer is the WPF one?

Comment: @Cameron: There are three timers typically used for Windows Forms apps: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer`, and `System.Threading.Timer`. `DispatcherTimer` is the WPF equivalent (not really equivalent, but analogous) of the Windows Forms timer.